# NDSolve solution is non sequential to be used in replace

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation and I need to obtain the solution and evaluate it just after. The reason for this is that I need to give the values x, u and t as parameters, which I think should be done in a module. 
Somehow when I evaluate, I get the error "ReplaceAll::reps: {sol} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing." This only happens the first time I run it, if I run it a second time, it is like mathematica realizes that the solution does exist and lets me use it as replace just fine. This is my specific problem with some parameters:

```
σA = 0.2;
σX = 0.4;
sD = 0.13;
sS = 0.2;
ϕ = 95/100;
gA = (σX^2 (σX^2 (1 - ϕ) + \
σA^2))/(σX^2 + σA^2);
 gB = (σX^2 σA^2)/(σX^2 + σA^2);
γA1[t_] := 1/(  t (1/sD^2 + ϕ^2/sS^2) + 1/gA);
γB1[t_] := sD^2/ (t + sD^2/gB);
PDEC = - 2 HC[
     p] (γB1[-p + u]/sD^2 - ( 
      x (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/sD^2) + ( (
    x (x - 1))/(2 sD^2)) + 
   2 HC[p]^2 ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
      sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2) - 
   Derivative[1][HC][p];
x = 1/3; u = 25; t = 0.1; sol = 
 NDSolve[{PDEC == 0, HC[0] == 0}, 
  HC, {p, Re[(u - t) - 0.1], Re[(u - t) + 0.1]}]; Evaluate[
 HC[25 - 0.1] /. sol]
```

Comment: Your code runs perfectly fine on my computer. Try running in a fresh kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Mathematica digests the code block, it see the `Evaluate` and tries to act on it immediately. This also means it would use the value of `sol` from the previous time you ran the block, which may not be your intent. Just get rid of `Evaluate` from the next to last line.

```
σA = 0.2;
σX = 0.4;
sD = 0.13;
sS = 0.2;
ϕ = 95/100;
gA = (σX^2 (σX^2 (1 - ϕ) + \
σA^2))/(σX^2 + σA^2);
gB = (σX^2 σA^2)/(σX^2 + σA^2);
γA1[t_] := 1/(  t (1/sD^2 + ϕ^2/sS^2) + 1/gA);
γB1[t_] := sD^2/ (t + sD^2/gB);
PDEC = - 2 HC[
     p] (γB1[-p + u]/sD^2 - ( 
      x (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/sD^2) + ( (
      x (x - 1))/(2 sD^2)) + 
   2 HC[p]^2 ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
      sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2) - 
   Derivative[1][HC][p];
x = 1/3; u = 25; t = 0.1; sol = 
 NDSolve[{PDEC == 0, HC[0] == 0}, 
        HC, {p, Re[(u - t) - 0.1], Re[(u - t) + 0.1]}]; 

(* Take out the Evaluate[ ] *)
HC[25 - 0.1] /. sol
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    \[Sigma]A = 0.2;
    \[Sigma]X = 0.4;
    sD = 0.13;
    sS = 0.2;
    \[Phi] = 95/100;
    gA = (\[Sigma]X^2 (\[Sigma]X^2 (1 - \[Phi]) + \
    \[Sigma]A^2))/(\[Sigma]X^2 + \[Sigma]A^2);
    gB = (\[Sigma]X^2 \[Sigma]A^2)/(\[Sigma]X^2 + \[Sigma]A^2);
    \[Gamma]A1[t_] := 1/(t (1/sD^2 + \[Phi]^2/sS^2) + 1/gA);
    \[Gamma]B1[t_] := sD^2/(t + sD^2/gB);
    PDEC = {-2 HC[
           p] (\[Gamma]B1[-p + u]/
             sD^2 - (x (\[Gamma]B1[-p + u] - \[Gamma]A1[-p + u]))/
             sD^2) + ((x (x - 1))/(2 sD^2)) + 
         2 HC[p]^2 ((\[Gamma]B1[-p + u] - \[Gamma]A1[-p + u])^2/
             sD^2 + (\[Phi]^2 (\[Gamma]A1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2) - 
         Derivative[1][HC][p] == 0};


    x = 1/3; u = 25; t = 0.1; 
    sol = NDSolve[{PDEC, HC[0] == 0}, 
      HC[p], {p, Re[(u - t) - 0.1], Re[(u - t) + 0.1]}];


    Plot[Evaluate[First[HC[p] /. %]], {p, 0, 20}]
    Evaluate[First[HC[p] /. sol]] /. p -> (25 - 0.1)
```